# Lightning component button not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, visualforce-component

Below is my lightning component which calls a VF Page

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >

   <!-- attribute to accept Visualforce page's javascript method -->
   <aura:attribute name="TTDLetter" type="object"/>

   <!-- Button component to invoke PDF download -->
   <lightning:button label="PDF" 
        onclick="{!c.PDF}" />
</aura:component>
```

My VF page

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
<style>
body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }

@page{
    size: letter;
    margin:10%;
    @top-left{
        content: "Dear,";
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    @bottom-right{
        content: "Yours Sincerely,";
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
}
    </style>
</head>
    <div align="right"><strong>Date</strong>: {!DAY(Today())} {!CASE(MONTH(Today()), 1, 'January', 2, 'February', 3, 'March', 4, 'April', 5, 'May', 6, 'June', 7, 'July', 8, 'August', 9, 'September', 10, 'October', 11, 'November', 12, 'December', 'Unknown')} {!YEAR(Today())}</div>
<center>
    <h1> Letter</h1>
    </center>
    <p>{!custom_object__C.Name__C}</p>    
</apex:page>
```

For the Lightning component If have created a quick action called "PDF", when I have clicked on PDF button from my object , I got a error stating :

> A Component Error has occurred!.

Can anyone just state me where I got my error as i got stuck here

Comment: normally, there is an actual error message other than "a component error has ocurred" mind sharing it VErbatim? additionally, have you tried anything to troubleshoot? it will help narrow down where you might be getting this error and will help others help you. Additionally, I dont see how your VF page is related to your lightning component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating your lightning component, have you tried creating a new custom button with a 'Visualforce Page' content source ?

Displaying VF pages rendered as PDF via this button works fine for me in LEX.

You will have to make a few changes to your VF Page in order to make it available for your button :

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
```

becomes

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="yourObjectApiName" extensions="MyController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: yes i have a onclick JS button : window.open("apex/Letter?Id={!_Letter__c.Id}","_blank");

Comment: Where should this button appear ? Onclick JS buttons are not supported in LEX

Comment: Yes, this button is for Classic as it doesn't support LEX I have written the lightning action n created  a quick action "pdf" for that, but it is unable to generate the PDF which was generated through my VF page

Comment: Okay, I understand that you keep your onclick JS button for Classic. Are you trying to access the VF Page to render as a PDF in your component's JS controller ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that. But I got stuck with this as I'm unable to find out where I got the mistake. The error message was: Uncaught Unknown controller action 'PDF'

Comment: Can you please share the JS controller code ?

Comment: /* Component controller */
({
 PDF : function(Letter, event, helper){

  var LetterProc = Letter.get("v.Letter");
  var dataToSend = {
      {!Letter.vfp}
  };

  LetterProc(dataToSend, function(){
  });
 }
})

Comment: In your PDF js function, try to use this line instead : 
sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/VFPageName?Parameter1=data1');

Comment: you're welcome. Did it solve your issue ?